# How to exclude row values that contain a certain text in SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
Select (sum(psip.likes + psip.comments + psip.video_views)/sum(psip.influencer_starting_followers)) as ER, cc.medium, count(*) as Base
From `public_collaboration_contents` as cc 
Left join `public_collaborations` as c ON cc.collaboration_id = c.id
Left join `public_influencers` as i on c.influencer_id = i.id
Left join `public_collaboration_tasks` as ct on cc.id = ct.collaboration_content_id
Left join `public_sponsored_instagram_posts`as psip on psip.brand_id=c.brand_id
Where cc.state = 'delivered'
And ct.state = 'delivered'
Group by cc.medium
```

the query above, returns rows under the "medium" columns that are named, "Clip" and "live"

I would like to exclude both of those. How can i add in an exclude clause? I tried writing the below query and adding it before the Group By, but im getting an error

````
exclude (select medium from public_collaboration_contents where medium='clip', medium='live') 
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `Where cc.state = 'delivered'` with `Where cc.state = 'delivered' and cc.medium not like'%clip%' and cc.medium not like '%live%'`

Answer (score 0):

Since you've stated your exclusion wanted to be `where medium='clip', medium='live'` your best option would be to add them into the WHERE clause itself.

`WHERE cc.state = 'delivered' AND cc.medium != 'clip' AND cc.medium != 'live'`

Using this instead of `LIKE '%live%'` can prevent your query from being seriously slowed down, if I remember correctly.

Additionally, you could replace `!=` with `<>` as they mean the same thing.